# непонятный результат в приведении типов, unsigned char

Tags: c

Имеется переменная `a` типа `unsigned char`. Пусть её значением является `0xa5`. Далее идёт вызов функции `func`, прототип которой следующий:

```
void func(char *data);
```

следующим образом

```
func(&a);
```

Смотрю в `gdb` значением `&a`:

```
p &a
(unsigned char *) 0x43e773 <a> "\245\260\006D"
p /a "\245"
{0xffffffa5, 0}
```

Вместо `a5`, там почему-то первым элементом идёт `ffffffa5`. Хотелось бы понять механизм преобразования и, собственно, почему так происходит.

Comment: [Раз](http://xxo.su/resizer/i/3/2/eaac627c.png), [два](http://xxo.su/resizer/i/7/1/4884cda.png).

Comment: @PinkTux, сильно :)

Comment: Собсно, это и есть gdb. То есть nemiver, но в линуксе всё - гуй к gdb :-) Как правильно смотреть память без гуя уже не помню, но к тому, что подозреваю какая-то мелочь у вас упущена...

Comment: да-да,я уже понял, спасибо. Это, скорее, даже затуп обычный был :)

Comment: Но при чем здесь какая-то `func`? Какое отношение `func` имеет к вопросу?

Comment: @Setplus Очень похоже на то, что произошло временное расширение знака. Дизассемблированный код бы увидеть. И, собственно, в чём проблема то?

Comment: @AnT, при переходе внутрь функции происходил просмотр значений.

Comment: @kisssko, да как оказалось, в моей банальной невнимательности :)

Comment: @Setplus: Так а что такое `a` "при переходе внутрь функции"? Откуда у вас вообще взялось `a` внутри функции?

Comment: @AnT, это адрес

Comment: @Setplus: Еще раз: если `a` объявлено в вызывающей функции, то внутри функции `func` у вас никакого `a` не будет и никакого `p &a` вы сделать не сможете. Поэтому возникает вопрос: о каком `a` и о каком `p &a` вы вообще ведете речь?

Comment: @AnT, переменная глобальная. Но это уже не суть важно, поскольку первый комментарий разрешил мой ступор.

Comment: @Setplus: Тогда опять не понятно, при чем здесь вызов функции. У вас что ли без вызова функции наблюдается другой вывод от `p &a`?

Comment: @AnT, да уже неважно. если честно, я сам запутался :(

Comment: @AnT, да всё нормуль. По нужному адресу лежит нужное значение, вопрос только в правильной визуализации :) И расширение до инта тут не при чём.

Comment: @PinkTux: Ну как я понял вопрос был в первую очередь про `p /a "\245"` и соответствующий вывод `0xffffffa5`.

Comment: @AnT, вот чесслово, забыл уже как оно в консоли и что какие команды gdb делают. Набрал код, который предполагался, скомпилил (без -g, само собой), проверил в первом попавшемся по руку гуе - всё нормуль :)